# Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$. Show that there is c>0 such that $f(x) > g(x) + c$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I unsure how to approach this problem....any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I understand that since f and g are continuous and bounded, then f and g must be uniformly continuous.

Comment: Consider $f-g>0$. You also know that it must achieve a global minimum $m$ on $[a,b]$ somewhere and hence $m>0$. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a "naive" approach. But if
$$
f(x)>g(x), \ \forall x \in [a,b],
$$
then 
$$
f(x)\geq g(x)+c_1 ,\ \forall x \in [a,b], \ \textrm{for some} \ c_1>0.
$$
But 
$$
g(x)+c_1 > g(x) + \frac{c_1}{2}, \ \forall x \in [a,b],
$$
so we simply put $c= \frac{c_1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

As $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, $f$ and $g$ reach their respective bounds on $[a,b]$ (and are bounded). The function $f-g$ is also continuous, bounded and reaches its bounds on $[a,b]$, since $f-g$ is continuous while $f$ and $g$ are continuous. If you take

$$c=\frac{1}{2}\min\left\{f(x)-g(x)\,\vert\,x\in[a,b]\right\}$$

it is clear that $c$ fits the required property.